# React app showing page with "404 the requested path could not be found" when using Apache

Tags: reactjs, apache, serve

I am deploying a React app to my Apache server.

I can access the app on my-ip:5001, but when I go to my domain it gives me 
"404 the requested path could not be found". Btw. the domain has been set up and worked with an html file before working with react.

[image]

I did `npm run build` and placed the build folder in the root of my server.
Made no changes to the package.json file.

I run the server using:  `serve -s -l 5001`

Apache conf file:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>    
        ServerName somedomain.com
        ServerAlias www.somedomain.com



ProxyRequests On
ProxyVia On
<Proxy *>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
  </Proxy>

        ProxyPass / http://localhost:5001/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5001/



</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Any idea what might be going on here?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 9):

run serve -s from inside of the /build folder. exemple

C:\Users\zafriha\Desktop\myProject>build>cd..

C:\Users\zafriha\Desktop\myProject>npm install -g serve

C:\Users\zafriha\Desktop\myProject>serve -s build

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.
Executing [nx reset](https://nx.dev/packages/nx/documents/reset#reset) in the terminal solved it.

```
nx reset
```

Answer (score 0):

You should run the command for production mode like 'npm run start' instead of using 'serve'. (for Dockerfile as well)

Comment: `npm run start` is a shortcut for `react-scripts start`, which starts a development server; it is not meant to be used on production servers

Comment: you should have 'npm run dev' command for development environment

Comment: I'm telling you that for `create-react-app` the `npm run start` commands is used for starting the dev server. And `create-react-app` is (most likely) what people are using unless they specify they are using a more advanced framework. My guess is that you are using `nextjs`, which has `run dev` and `run start` commands and you assumed the OP is using `nextjs` as well, but there is nothing in the question that may indicate they are using `nextjs`, so your advice to use `run start` will not apply to them, since in their project there is no built-in command to serve files.

Comment: yes you are right in my case it was nextjs now i see what you meant thanks

Answer (score -1):

New answer:
There is no need to run the serve command on the server.
Just put the build folder on the server. Inside the .conf apache file make the DocumentRoot path point to the build folder.

Old answer:
Changing these lines:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:5001/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5001/
```

to:

```
ProxyPass / http://my-server-ip:5001/
ProxyPassReverse / http://my-server-ip:5001/
```

solved the problem

Comment: Sorry but, can't be seen on 'Search Files' where can we see it?